# Iterating over lines in a file with "for" in shell never matching target

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

i wrote a shell script as you can see followed. The script reads all line which in .dat file and writes screen matching words according to specified parameter but if/else block doesn't properly.Both block if and else fired same time.

**sh file**

```
#!/bin/bash
p="*.dat"
k="$1"
for f in $p
do
    if [ "$k" == "$f" ]; then
        echo "$f present"
    else
        echo "not found $k"
    fi
    cat $f
done
```

**dat file**

```
lorem
ipsum
loremium
dolor
sit
amet
ipso
```

**terminal**

```
$ ./loc.sh lor
```

**result**

```
not found lor
lorem
ipsum
loremium
dolor
sit
amet
ipso
```

Comment: *"Both block if and else fired same time"* -- this isn't actually shown in your output, which doesn't contain the word "present" anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for aid. Actually i'm trying for hours, i wrote here when i face difficultly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code didn't ever look inside of a file until *after* running the comparison -- it merely compared the **name** of each `.dat` file to the target, and allowed only exact matches (not substrings).

Consider instead:

```
while read -r line; do
  if [[ $line = *"$1"* ]]; then
    echo "$1 present in $line"
  else
    echo "$1 not found in $line"
  fi
done < <(cat *.dat)
```

- Using `cat *.dat` combines all the files into a single stream. Enclosing this in `<(cat *.dat)` generates a filename which can read from to yield that stream; using `< <(cat *.dat)` redirects stdin from this file (within the scope of the `while` loop for which this redirection takes place).
- Using `while read` processes an input stream line-by-line (see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)).
- Using a test of `[[ $line = *"$1"* ]]` allows the target (contents of `$1`) to be found *inside* a line, instead of only matching when `$1` matches the entire line as a whole. You can also have this effect with `[[ $line =~ "$1" ]]`. *Note that the quotes are mandatory for correct operation in either of these cases.*
- Using a `for` loop to iterate over lines is extremely poor practice; see [Don't Read Lines With For](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). If you want to use a `for` loop, use it to iterate over *files* instead:

  ```
  for f in *.dat; do
    # handle case where no files exist
    [[ -e "$f" ]] || continue 
    # read each given file
    while read -r line; do
      if [[ $line = *"$1"* ]]; then
        echo "$1 present in $line in file $f"
      else
        echo "$1 not present in $line in file $f"
      fi
    done <"$f"
  done
  ```